# Создайте массив заполненый случайными значениями, вычислите среднее арифметическое, затем создайте два массива используя среднее арифм

Tags: java, случайные-числа, split

**Задача полностью**

1. Создайте массив переменных int  размером в 100 элементов
   заполненых случайными значениями. 2. Затем вычислите среднее арифметическое значений в массиве, **3. затем создайте два массива где в одном, сохраните все значения, меньшие среднего, а во втором - все значения, которые больше или равны среднему значению.**

1 и 2 мне удалось сделать, не пойму как разделить массив и избавиться от нулей (№3)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


     int[] randomNumbers = new int[100];
     int[] greaterList = new int[100];
     int[] smallerlist = new int[100];

     int sum = 0;
     double avg = 0;
     int greaterListIndex = 0;
     int  smallerlistIndex = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++)
      {
          int n = rand.nextInt(1000);
          randomNumbers[i] = n;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Numbers " + randomNumbers[i]);
        }

      for( int num : randomNumbers) {
          sum = sum+num;
          avg = (double)sum / randomNumbers.length;
      }
      System.out.println("Sum of array elements is:"+sum);
      System.out.println("Avegare:" + avg);



      for(int j = 0; j < randomNumbers.length; j++){
            if (randomNumbers[j] > avg)
                greaterList[greaterListIndex] = randomNumbers[j];
            greaterListIndex++;
        }

         System.out.println("Numbers greater than the average are: "); 
        for( int k = 0; k < greaterListIndex; k++) {
        System.out.print(greaterList[k]+",");
 }

          for(int j = 0; j < randomNumbers.length; j++){
                if (randomNumbers[j] < avg)
                    smallerlist[smallerlistIndex] = randomNumbers[j];
                smallerlistIndex++;
            }
          System.out.println();

                System.out.println("Numbers smaller than the average are: "); 
            for( int k = 0; k < smallerlistIndex; k++) {
            System.out.print(smallerlist[k]+",");
     }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вычисление среднеарифметического, по моему, можно вынести за цикл

```
 for( int num : randomNumbers) {
     sum = sum+num;    
    }
 avg = (double)sum / randomNumbers.length;
 System.out.println("Sum of array elements is:"+sum);
 System.out.println("Avegare:" + avg);
```

Будем пользоваться далее так же массивами int[]

```
    int[] middleLess = new int[100];//массив для значений < avg
    int[] middleMore = new int[100];//массив для значений >= avg
    //по умолчанию в массивах middleLess и middleMore все значения равны 0
    int z = -1;//приготовим счетчик для middleLess
    int y = -1;//приготовим счетчик для middleMore
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        middleLess[i] = -1;//присвоим каждому значению -1, потому что в нашем рандоме может встречаться 0, а нам не нужно смешивать значения равным нулю в старом и новом массивах
        middleMore[i] = -1;//аналогично
        if (randomNumbers[i] < avg) {
            middleLess[++z] = randomNumbers[i];//начинаем разделять, ++z увеличивает на единицу порядковое место добавляемого значения в массив со значения < avg
        } else {
            middleMore[++y] = randomNumbers[i];//.... >= avg
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < middleLess.length; i++) {
        if (middleLess[i] > -1) {
            System.out.println("middleLess " + middleLess[i] + " < " + avg);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < middleMore.length; i++) {
        if (middleMore[i] > -1) {
            System.out.println("middleMore " + middleMore[i] + " >= " + avg);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("middleLess.length - " + z + " middleMore.length - " + y);
```

[На выходе](https://ideone.com/zHPm9u)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[100];
    int[] less = null;
    int[] more = null;
    int sum = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);
        sum += randomNumbers[i];
        System.out.println("Numbers " + randomNumbers[i]);
    }

    avg = (double) sum / randomNumbers.length;
    Arrays.sort(randomNumbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (randomNumbers[i]>=avg) {
            less = Arrays.copyOfRange(randomNumbers, 0, i);
            more = Arrays.copyOfRange(randomNumbers, i, randomNumbers.length);
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sum of array elements is:" + sum);
    System.out.println("Average:" + avg);

    System.out.println("LESS ARRAY: " + Arrays.toString(less));
    System.out.println("MORE ARRAY: " + Arrays.toString(more));

}
```

Comment: У вас много лишних циклов в коде... Если вам нужны именно 2 массива, то можно решить так. При массиве в 100 элементов сортировка - тривиальная задача. Если же элементов будет очень много, то лучше брать две коллекции и, перебирая массив в цикле, сравнивать значения со средним арифметическим, в зависимости от результата добавлять элемент в одну из коллекций. В любом случае из ArrayList получить массив не составляет труда. ведь ArrayList по сути и есть массив.